# Which has higher performance in phonegap? Canvas or HTML Elements?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, android-canvas

Imagine we want to create a **cross-platform** (iOS, Android, Win...) app using PhoneGap (and we are as expert as to know that native-apps has higher performance in contrast with using a framework but anyway we just decided to do it with PhoneGap).

```
The app is really simple 2 pages (LOGIN/REGISTER) and nothing more.
```

We are handling the login and registration process somehow with JAVA 
**and it's not matter for us now.**

What is just matter is the performance of the user interface (**including time of initializing the app and motion and transition of pages inside of the app**). We implemented two pages (LOGIN/REGISTER) with HTML elements (Form, Input, ...) and there's a button for switch between two pages with sliding effect and we used jQuery mobile for that.

> The question is if we all forget about he **STRATEGY** of using HTML
>   elements and jQuery mobile and instead using a new strategy which is
>   **creating canvas and using a library like KineticJS** or other similar library inside
>   and implementing our LOGIN/REGISTER and TRANSITIONS (slidding effect) 
>   **all inside of the canvas**

.

> **will this change of strategy affect the performance of the app**?
>
> ---
>
> **and if the answer is yes in which direction? The performance will increase or decrease**?

Comment: if you want performance forget jquery and phonegap.best is don't use any library.especially if you do simple stuff.canvas 2d should be faster then 2d transitions.anyway using 3dtransitions enables the hardwareacceleration on the devices.you can use 3d transitions to create 2d slide effects.

Comment: if you extend your queston and add some more info about what you need in this 2 simple pages (the transitions) i can show you some native examples.

Comment: and as it's just for mobile devices, you just need the -webkit and the -ms prefixes.

Comment: phonegap is slow as hell even on top devices if your UI is not trivial. Even when it's not slow the user feels the difference and the different feeling is often disturbing. I've tried it in many apps before definitely discarding it. Your case can be handled easily with a simple native webview if you can't do it fully native.

Comment: @elbuild thanks. But without phonegap how can i invoke Java functions for more complex processes using javascript?

Comment: You can use inapp:// links and handle them in the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method of your webview.